# Java Map<> with intrisic types possible?

Tags: java, hashmap

How is this possible:
`HashMap<byte[], byte[]>` and what is hash() of byte[]?

Comment: What's so strange about it? Arrays are object, so it's allowed.

Comment: `System.out.println(new byte[10].hashCode());` gives me `209777867`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (with a big caveat, see below), but `byte[]` is not an "intrinsic type". First, there's no such thing, you *probably* mean a "primitive type". Second: `byte[]` is *not* a primitive type, `byte` is. An array is *always* a reference type.

Arrays don't have specific `hashCode` implementations, so they'll just use the [`hashCode` of `Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), which means that the `hashCode` will be [the indentity-`hashCode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29), which is independent from the actual content.

In other words: a `byte[]` is a very bad `Map` key, because you can only retrieve the value with the **exact same instance**.

If you need a content-based `hashCode()` based on an array, you can use [`Arrays.hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28byte%5B%5D%29), but that won't help you (directly) with the `Map`. There's also [`Arrays.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29) to check for content equality.

You *could* wrap your `byte[]` in a thin wrapper object that implements `hashCode()` and `equals()` (using the methods mentioned above):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class ArrayWrapper {
  private final byte[] data;
  private final int hash;

  public ArrayWrapper(final byte[] data) {
    // strictly speaking we should make a defensive copy here,
    // but I *assume* (and should document) that the argument
    // passed in here should not be changed
    this.data = data;
    this.hash = Arrays.hashCode(data);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return hash
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof ArrayWrapper)) {
      return false;
    }
    ArrayWrapper other = (ArrayWrapper) o;
    return this.hash == other.hash && Arrays.equals(this.data, other.data);
  }
  // don't add getData to prevent having to do a defensive copy of data
}
```

Using this class you can then use a `Map<ArrayWrapper,byte[]>`.

Comment: Array probably can be used with TreeMap if you implement your custom Comparator.

Comment: @AlexR: that could work, but note that such a `TreeMap` would **not** correctly implement the `Map` interface, since that requires the `Comparator` to be consistent with `equals()` (i.e. `compare(a,b)` bust return `0` **iff** `a.equals(b)`).

Answer (score 2):

For arrays `hashCode()` uses the default implementation from `Object` - typically some form of internal object address. As a result, key in this `HashMap` is considered unique if it is a different array, not if array contents are equal.

```
byte[] a = { 2, 3 };
byte[] b = { 2, 3 };
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // false
Map<byte[], String> map = new HashMap<byte[], String>();
map.put(a, "A");
map.put(b, "B");
System.out.println(map); // {[B@37d2068d=B, [B@7ecec0c5=A}
```